# javascript loop every 9 seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am developing a html5 app and i want that after 8 seconds of writing the random place it will write if you have won or not for one second and then it will begin from creating a new random, i've tried that with for but it do'esnt seem to make anything and if i write while(true) the browser crashes.

is there any way to fix it?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    ImageClicked = false;
    for (var i=0;i<8;i++){
        var XYScore = 0;
        var RandomPlace=Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);
        var Place;
        var WantedXPr;
        var WantedYPr;

        switch(RandomPlace){
            case 1:
                Place="Berlin";
                WantedYPr=790;
                WantedXPr=4300;
                break;
            case 2:
                Place="New York";
                WantedYPr=1061;
                WantedXPr=2345;
                break;
            case 3:
                Place="barcelona";
                WantedYPr=1049;
                WantedXPr=4046;
                break;
            case 4:
                Place="Johannesburg";
                WantedYPr=2546;
                WantedXPr=4618;
                break;
            case 5:
                Place="shanghai";
                WantedYPr=1272;
                WantedXPr=6664;
                break;
            case 6:
                Place="Moskau";
                WantedYPr=732;
                WantedXPr=4800;
                break;
            case 7:
                Place="kahir";
                WantedYPr=4690;
                WantedXPr=1310;
                break;
            case 8:
                Place="Delhi";
                WantedYPr=1323;
                WantedXPr=5707;
                break;
            case 9:
                Place="rio de genero";
                WantedYPr=2478;
                WantedXPr=3050;
                break;
            case 10:
                Place="Tokyo";
                WantedYPr=1180;
                WantedXPr=7102;
                break;
        }

        setTimeout(function(){
            if (ImageClicked==false){
                $('#HeaderAfterWrite').html(", all the people were killed");
                $('#HeaderWrite').html("No one helped ");}
            else if(XYScore>69)
                $('#HeaderWrite').html("Youv'e succesful recover the city ");
            else if(XYScore>39)
                $('#HeaderWrite').html("The Parvars are not all of ");
            else {$('#HeaderAfterWrite').html("is full destroyed now!");
                $('#HeaderWrite').html(" ");}
        }, 8000);
        $('#Place').html(Place);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use a setInterval for this purpose

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval)

```
time=setInterval(function(){
//your code
},9000);
```

you can clear this by

```
clearInterval(time);
```

Comment: Other than naming the interval identifier `time`, good answer. ...well, and w3schools is a rather poor reference. but +1 nonetheless.

Answer (score 7):

This is more elegant.

```
(function loop() {
  setTimeout(function () {
    // execute script
    loop()
  }, 9000);
}());
```

Answer (score 1):

yes there is a way to fix it.

make a function of the timeout.

```
function setTimeoutAgain()
{
   var t = setTimeout(function()
   {
        setTimeoutAgain();
   },8000);
}
```

Comment: how do i paste it in my code(im just a beginner in javascript)?