# Is it possible to make a "random" but static text display in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Alright, so what I'm looking for is something I can't really put a name to.

It's similar to scrolling text, except I don't want it to scroll.  Maybe a little fade in/out effect if possible, but that's totally optional.

Basically, this is for an area on a website with limited vertical space.  I have an area of, let's say 120 characters wide and 4 lines vertical, and that's all.

I have a list of song quotes.  Right now it's a text file, and I can format it as however.  (meaning if I need to put one quote per text, name it lyric1.txt, lyric2.txt, lyric3.txt, that's fine... or if I put an extra blank line between them, that works too. Whatever is necessary.)

What I want to do is display one set of lyrics at a time.  They vary in length, but they will all fit in my limited area.  Have it display for, let's say 2 minutes, then change to a different set of lyrics.

So essentially what I'm trying to do is have a static area of text that changes what text is displayed every X amount of seconds, in order to prevent scrolling or cropping.

If it won't work as a time-based thing, having it show a different selection each time the page is loaded (or refreshed) would also work.

Something tells me Javascript is capable of doing this, but I really don't know where to start.

Comment: do you need a carousel? http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: So you're developing the page yourself? Meaning you can change the source code any way you want? Maybe something [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13586008/javascript-loop-every-9-seconds)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys. That carousel thing looks pretty neat, I might play around with it.

Comment: It seems as though you're not interested in solving the problem yourself. Consider hiring a programmer to do it for you. If you *are* interested in solving your own problem, you need to show [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I AM interested in solving it myself, but I have no idea where to start.  We need a "beginner" version of stack overflow where people can post questions like this without getting chastised for it...

Answer (score -2):

You can use `<marquee>` tag of html. after some period of time you can change the text inside of `<marquee>` tag with help of javascript.

Simple use of marquee is :

```
<marquee>This is basic example of marquee</marquee>
```